# How to catch errors in elua (namely NodeMCU)

Tags: lua, try-catch, nodemcu

Let's say I'm importing something with:

```
t = require("ds18b20")
t.setup(1)
temperatura = t.read()
```

How do I catch an error like "Failed import"?

Doing stuff like pcall(t.setup(1)) just returns a syntax error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the error is raised by `require` not finding `ds18b20`, then you can do

```
ok, t = pcall(require, "ds18b20")
if not ok then
  -- handle error, t has error message
else
  -- can use t
end
```